# How to add a request body to spring mockmvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, mockito

I have the following post endpoint:

```
   @PostMapping(path = "/migration/sendStatements")
   public void sendStatements(@RequestBody StatementsDTO StatementsDTO) 
   {....}
```

I would like to test this method. I am using Spring MVC and in my test class, I am using MockMVC.

When I try writing the method:
`mockMvc.perform(post("/migration/sendStatements"));` I don't get an option to add a request body. I want to add a request body to this endpoint. How do i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add request body using `content` method

```
String requestBody = "{.... }";
mockMvc.perform(post("/migration/sendStatements")
   .content(requestBody));
```